# String concatenation and memory managment

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have been using C++ for some time and there's still at least one thing I cannot manage to understand, nor I could find a good explanation surfing on the Web. It has something to do with memory managment and can be illustraded with this example:

Consider the string concatenation operator of std::string which looks like this

> std::string operator+(const string& s1, string& s2)

which, as everybody knows, returns a newly created object (another std::string) containing the two original string concatenated.
My question is: how is this possible? where does this object lies in memory?

I mean, if I had to write the function implementation I would do something like this

```
std::string std::string::operator+(const string& s1, string& s2)
{
std::string *res=new std::string;
// fill res with the content of s1 and s2
return *res;
}
```

but in this way I know I would cause a memory leak because if I called the function one million times I would generate one million strings which wouldn't be deallocated until the program's end. On the other hand I could do this:

```
std::string& std::string::operator+(const string& s1, string& s2)
{
std::string res;
// fill res with the content of s1 and s2
return res;
}
```

But in this way i would return a reference to a local variable which becomes garbage as soon as the function returns.
Finally I could simply write

```
std::string std::string::operator+(const string& s1, string& s2)
{
std::string res;
// fill res with the content of s1 and s2
return res;
}
```

and pass the result by value, this should accomplish the mission but seems to me very inefficient because I have to copy the whole res (which in theory could be very large) object to the calling function.
I say this because I'm actually working on a linear algebra library and it would be very nice to perform e.g. matrix addition with just

```
m3=m1+m2;
```

just as with string concatenation, but if the only solution is to copy back the resulting object, it is unpratical with a double matrix of, say, 100MB. At the moment the function I use is

```
matrix& matrix::sum(matrix& m1, matrix& m2)
```

which get used in this way

```
m3.sum(m2,m1);
```

which looks ugly and also prevents me from summing multiple matrix in a single line, I have to write

```
m4.sum(m1,m2)
m4.sum(m4,m3)
```

or

```
(m4.sum(m1,m2)).(m4,m3)
```

if I really want to make it in a single line but it is absolutely unreadable.

Is there a better way to do all this stuff?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your last `string` example doesn't copy at all. The copy gets elided. This is the preferred style.

Comment: It returns by value. Read up on [return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization). Implementations are allowed to elide copies under certain circumstances. That makes returning by value OK in many cases where naively it would look inefficient.

Comment: RVO is useful here however note that short of other optimisations the way the standard libraries work can be quite more complex. For instance, MSVC does a malloc and free when doing something like `s = s + "a"` where `s` is a `string`. The `string` internally keeps a pointer to some memory and when it needs to grow it will allocate new memory and delete the old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been pointed out, in cases like an overloaded
`operator+`, you have to return a complete object (by value).
Generally, this is less of an issue than one imagines; things
like RVO make it even less of an issue.  In the case of (large)
matrices, on the other hand, it can become a serious issue, not
just because of runtime, but because of memory considerations;
if you have an expression like:

```
m = m1 + m2 + m3 + m4 + m5;
```

there will be four temporaries, and they will all last until the
end of the full expression.  If the matrices are large, that can
exert significant memory pressure.  In such cases, the usual
technique is to return some special type, which simply keeps
pointers to the left and right hand arguments; `operator=` (and
a constructor) is then overload to take this type, and builds
the final matrix dynamically.  Something like:

```
class MatrixProxy
{
    void* operator new( size_t );   //  Prevent dynamic allocation
public:
    virtual int rows() const = 0;
    virtual int columns() const = 0;
    virtual double get( int row, int column ) const = 0;
};

class MatrixOpAddResults : public MatrixProxy
{
    MatrixProxy const* lhs;
    MatrixProxy const* rhs;
public:
    MatrixOpAddResults( Matrix const& lhs, Matrix const& rhs )
        : lhs( &lhs )
        , rhs( &rhs )
    {
        assert( lhs->rows() == rhs->rows() && lhs->columns() == rhs->columns() );
    }
    int rows() const override
    {
        return lhs->rows();
    }
    int columns() const override
    {
        return lhs->columns();
    }
    double get( int row, int column ) const override
    {
        return lhs->get( row, column ) + rhs->get( row, column );
    }
};

MatrixProxy operator+( MatrixProxy const& lhs, MatrixProxy const& rhs )
{
    return MatrixProxy( lhs, rhs );
}
```

Then, for example...

```
Matrix::Matrix( MatrixProxy const& other )
    : m_rows( other.rows() )
    , m_columns( other.columns() )
    , m_data( other.rows() & other.columns() )
{
    std::vector<double>::const_iterator dest = m_data.begin();
    for ( int i = 0; i != m_rows; ++ i ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j != m_columns; ++ j ) {
            *dest = other.get( i, j );
            ++ dest;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, Matrix itself should derive from MatrixProxy as
well.  And you'll need a Results class for each operator.

The modern tendency would be to use templates, rather than
inheritance, here.  I find the inheritance based solution
clearer and more understandable, however (because it is more
explicit), at least for explaining the technique, and both
should ultimately generate exactly the same code (provided all
of the functions in the Results classes are inline).

Finally: unless this is for personal understanding, there are
several good libraries freely available which implement matrices
using the above technique.  (Blitz++ comes to mind, although
I don't know what its current status is.)

Comment: in case of `m = m1 + m2 + m3 + m4 + m5` there would be 4 temporaries but, I think, 3 of them would be destructed and last created from `(m1 + m2 + m3) + m4` would be assigned to `m` via copy elison. Right?

Comment: Nice answer, but it would be nicer if it were fixed up and maybe elaborated a bit. For example `return MatrixProxy(lhs,rhs)` will not even compile because the (abstract) base class MatrixProxy has no constructor...

Answer (score 5):

This version is correct

```
std::string std::string::operator+(const string& s1, string& s2)
{
    std::string res;
    // fill res with the content of s1 and s2
    return res;
}
```

Most compilers employ an optimization technique called *named return value optimization* to deal with the inefficiency of copying the value. It is expressly permitted by the standards, called *copy elision*.

In C++11 there is another way: when you return the string `res`, it becomes an r-value, and *move constructor* will be used in place of *copy constructor*, and that is cheap as well. But again, most compilers optimize away both copy and move.

At last, I don't know why you have to implement a matrix library by yourself. If it is not a homework, use Eigen instead. Optimizing matrix algebra is very hard work that requires a lot of low level understanding.

Answer (score 3):

Modern compilers will do "copy elision", which pretty much means that the last of your string examples doesn't actually copy the resulting string, it just stores the result in the place provided by the calling code. The same would clearly apply for a `vector` or a `matrix` of your own design.